# Npm server not available after docker compose

Tags: node.js, django, docker, npm

I'm fairly new to docker. I was trying to separate my web app on modules for backend (django), frontend (react) and with some postgres db.

Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./private/posgtesql/data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    working_dir: /app/label_it
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  front:
    build:
      context: ./label_it
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: front
    command: npm run dev
    working_dir: /app/label_it/front
    volumes:
      - ./label_it/front:/app/label_it/front
      - ./label_it/front/node-modules:/app/./label_it/front/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Django side runs like dream, browsing `127.0.0.1:8000` responses with server site. BUT.
There is nothing on 127.0.0.1:8001.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I should be getting both servers for django AND for react on respecting ports??

Searched whole internet looking for solution. All I found was to check if node server actually runs on `0.0.0.0:8001` and it does according to :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
baa18d3bfa73   labeling-lab-platform_front   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes   3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->8000/tcp   front
6a76ba3a901b   labeling-lab-platform_app     "python manage.py ru…"   About an hour ago   Up 24 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp             app
c0d1d27ed930   postgres                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up 24 minutes   5432/tcp                           postgres
```

It's my second day dealing with this issue and I'm realy stuck.

EDIT:
my package.json with declared dev server:

```
{
  "name": "static",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.20",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.17",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/unstyled": "^5.0.0-alpha.20",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "react-desktop-notification": "^1.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "react-window-infinite-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: show us your devServer config

Comment: Try by exposing 'app' container on different port instead of 8000. Avoid 8001.

Comment: @iklinac please, see my EDIT.

Comment: @SameerK I tried 3000:3000 with no result.

Comment: dev-server default port is 8080 but it might be different depending on your config https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverport